# iOS Depoyment : How to install a certificate locally to distribute app under different dev team?

Tags: ios, xcode

Our organisation (MyOrg) has a mobile application which we have licensed to another organisation (TheirOrg). In order to deploy the app for TheirOrg we need to make changes so it works in their environment (end points, icons, title, etc). So it makes sense to sign the app using their certificate. The goal is to have the ability to deploy the app either using our certificate or theirs.

This is what we've done so far:

1. 'TheirOrg' has made a request for us (MyOrg) to join their
   development team.
2. We joined the development team and downloaded the certificates. As I look in the KeyChain app I can see all certificates.
3. When it comes to deployment, through Archive option, I can see TheirOrg listed in the 'Development Team to use for provisioning' option. (This is great because this allows me to sign the app either using MyOrg or TheirOrg key.)
4. After selecting 'TheirOrg' from the dropdown and moving to the next screen I'm faced with the following error:

[image]

Here's my question: how do you instal the certificate locally through XCode (6.4)?

Comment: You need their p12 file, certificate won't work at your end.

Comment: reset certificate and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to ask them the `p12 certificate` (Export from `keychain` - distribution certificate) & then install it. then follow below instructions.

If you want to archive your app and export it, then you have to create iOS Distribution certificate not development certificate.

1. **Generate AdHoc Distribution provisioning profile**  [image]
2. Download and double click on it.
3. Select that profile on build settings & then try to Archieve, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for that @SibaPrasadHota - I'll request the p12 certificate from the other organisation and will update this question.